# How to use a Custom Spring Converter With a Grails Service

Tags: grails, spring-4

I have a custom Spring Converter of type GenericConverter. I try to wire it into a service like this...

```
resources.groovy
domainConverter(DomainConverter){bean -> bean.scope = 'prototype'; bean.autowire = "byName"}
```

---

```
class DomainService {
    def domainConverter
    DomainCommand convertDomain(Domain bd){
       bd as DomainCommand
    }

    Domain convertCommand(DomainCommand bc){
        bc as Domain
    }
}
```

This however seems to fail...

> Cannot cast object 'Domain(...)' with class 'Domain' to class
>   'DomainCommand'

Can someone help with what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
domainConverter(DomainConverter){bean -> bean.scope = 'prototype'; bean.autowire = "byName"}
domainConverterService(ConversionServiceFactoryBean){
  converters = ref("domainConverter")
}
```

In service...

```
def domainConverterService
def newCommand = domainConverterService.convert(domain, domain.class)
```